# cx_Oracle: Using PL/SQL Record as parameter to stored procedure

Tags: python, plsql, cx-oracle, oracle-ebs

I am attempting to pass a PL/SQL Record parameter to a Stored Procedure. I am using cx_Oracle 6.0b1. From the cx_Oracle documentation, I believe the following code to be correct, however, it always results in the error `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_VENDOR'`

My code:

```
import cx_Oracle

ID_MAX_LEN = 29


def get_obj_of_type(type_name, connection):
    type_name = type_name.replace('.', '_')[:ID_MAX_LEN]
    typeObj = connection.gettype(type_name)
    return typeObj.newobject()


def main():
    dsn = {...}
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn['user'], dsn['password'], dsn=dsn['oracle_dsn'])
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        rec = get_obj_of_type('AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG.R_VENDOR_REC_TYPE', connection)
        rec.VENDOR_NAME = 'Test Vendor'
        P_API_VERSION = 1.0
        P_INIT_MSG_LIST = "T"
        P_COMMIT = "T"
        P_VALIDATION_LEVEL = 1
        X_RETURN_STATUS = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
        X_MSG_COUNT = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
        X_MSG_DATA = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
        P_VENDOR_REC = rec
        X_VENDOR_ID = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
        X_PARTY_ID = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
        result = cursor.callproc('AP_VENDOR_PUB_PKG.CREATE_VENDOR',
                                 parameters=[P_API_VERSION,
                                             P_INIT_MSG_LIST,
                                             P_COMMIT,
                                             P_VALIDATION_LEVEL,
                                             X_RETURN_STATUS,
                                             X_MSG_COUNT,
                                             X_MSG_DATA,
                                             P_VENDOR_REC,
                                             X_VENDOR_ID,
                                             X_PARTY_ID])
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()


main()
```

This stored procedure is part of Oracle r12 E-Business Suite. If you have access to a database instance for that product, this stored procedure should be available.

The record definition, as requested by Anthony:

```
TYPE r_vendor_rec_type IS RECORD(
    VENDOR_ID           NUMBER,
    SEGMENT1            AP_SUPPLIERS.SEGMENT1%TYPE,
    VENDOR_NAME         AP_SUPPLIERS.VENDOR_NAME%TYPE,
    VENDOR_NAME_ALT         AP_SUPPLIERS.VENDOR_NAME_ALT%TYPE,
    SUMMARY_FLAG            AP_SUPPLIERS.SUMMARY_FLAG%TYPE,
    ENABLED_FLAG            AP_SUPPLIERS.ENABLED_FLAG%TYPE,
    SEGMENT2            AP_SUPPLIERS.SEGMENT2%TYPE,
    SEGMENT3            AP_SUPPLIERS.SEGMENT3%TYPE,
    SEGMENT4            AP_SUPPLIERS.SEGMENT4%TYPE,
    SEGMENT5            AP_SUPPLIERS.SEGMENT5%TYPE,
    EMPLOYEE_ID         NUMBER,
    VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE     AP_SUPPLIERS.VENDOR_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE%TYPE,
    CUSTOMER_NUM            AP_SUPPLIERS.CUSTOMER_NUM%TYPE,
    ONE_TIME_FLAG           AP_SUPPLIERS.ONE_TIME_FLAG%TYPE,
    PARENT_VENDOR_ID        NUMBER,
    MIN_ORDER_AMOUNT        NUMBER,
    TERMS_ID            NUMBER,
    SET_OF_BOOKS_ID         NUMBER,
    ALWAYS_TAKE_DISC_FLAG       AP_SUPPLIERS.ALWAYS_TAKE_DISC_FLAG%TYPE,
    PAY_DATE_BASIS_LOOKUP_CODE  AP_SUPPLIERS.PAY_DATE_BASIS_LOOKUP_CODE%TYPE,
    PAY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE       AP_SUPPLIERS.PAY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE%TYPE,
    PAYMENT_PRIORITY        NUMBER,
    INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE       AP_SUPPLIERS.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE%TYPE,
    PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE       AP_SUPPLIERS.PAYMENT_CURRENCY_CODE%TYPE,
    INVOICE_AMOUNT_LIMIT        NUMBER,
    HOLD_ALL_PAYMENTS_FLAG      AP_SUPPLIERS.HOLD_ALL_PAYMENTS_FLAG%TYPE,
    HOLD_FUTURE_PAYMENTS_FLAG   AP_SUPPLIERS.HOLD_FUTURE_PAYMENTS_FLAG%TYPE,
    HOLD_REASON         AP_SUPPLIERS.HOLD_REASON%TYPE,
    TYPE_1099           AP_SUPPLIERS.TYPE_1099%TYPE,
    WITHHOLDING_STATUS_LOOKUP_CODE  AP_SUPPLIERS.WITHHOLDING_STATUS_LOOKUP_CODE%TYPE,
    WITHHOLDING_START_DATE      AP_SUPPLIERS.WITHHOLDING_START_DATE%TYPE,
    ORGANIZATION_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE   AP_SUPPLIERS.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE%TYPE,
    START_DATE_ACTIVE       AP_SUPPLIERS.START_DATE_ACTIVE%TYPE,
    END_DATE_ACTIVE         AP_SUPPLIERS.END_DATE_ACTIVE%TYPE,
    MINORITY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE  AP_SUPPLIERS.MINORITY_GROUP_LOOKUP_CODE%TYPE,
    WOMEN_OWNED_FLAG        AP_SUPPLIERS.WOMEN_OWNED_FLAG%TYPE,
    SMALL_BUSINESS_FLAG     AP_SUPPLIERS.SMALL_BUSINESS_FLAG%TYPE,
    HOLD_FLAG           AP_SUPPLIERS.HOLD_FLAG%TYPE,
    PURCHASING_HOLD_REASON      AP_SUPPLIERS.PURCHASING_HOLD_REASON%TYPE,
    HOLD_BY             NUMBER,
    HOLD_DATE           AP_SUPPLIERS.HOLD_DATE%TYPE,
    TERMS_DATE_BASIS        AP_SUPPLIERS.TERMS_DATE_BASIS%TYPE,
    INSPECTION_REQUIRED_FLAG    AP_SUPPLIERS.INSPECTION_REQUIRED_FLAG%TYPE,
    RECEIPT_REQUIRED_FLAG       AP_SUPPLIERS.RECEIPT_REQUIRED_FLAG%TYPE,
    QTY_RCV_TOLERANCE       NUMBER,
    QTY_RCV_EXCEPTION_CODE      AP_SUPPLIERS.QTY_RCV_EXCEPTION_CODE%TYPE,
    ENFORCE_SHIP_TO_LOCATION_CODE   AP_SUPPLIERS.ENFORCE_SHIP_TO_LOCATION_CODE%TYPE,
    DAYS_EARLY_RECEIPT_ALLOWED  NUMBER,
    DAYS_LATE_RECEIPT_ALLOWED       NUMBER,
    RECEIPT_DAYS_EXCEPTION_CODE AP_SUPPLIERS.RECEIPT_DAYS_EXCEPTION_CODE%TYPE,
    RECEIVING_ROUTING_ID        NUMBER,
    ALLOW_SUBSTITUTE_RECEIPTS_FLAG  AP_SUPPLIERS.ALLOW_SUBSTITUTE_RECEIPTS_FLAG%TYPE,
    ALLOW_UNORDERED_RECEIPTS_FLAG   AP_SUPPLIERS.ALLOW_UNORDERED_RECEIPTS_FLAG%TYPE,
    HOLD_UNMATCHED_INVOICES_FLAG    AP_SUPPLIERS.HOLD_UNMATCHED_INVOICES_FLAG%TYPE,
    TAX_VERIFICATION_DATE       AP_SUPPLIERS.TAX_VERIFICATION_DATE%TYPE,
    NAME_CONTROL            AP_SUPPLIERS.NAME_CONTROL%TYPE,
    STATE_REPORTABLE_FLAG       AP_SUPPLIERS.STATE_REPORTABLE_FLAG%TYPE,
    FEDERAL_REPORTABLE_FLAG     AP_SUPPLIERS.FEDERAL_REPORTABLE_FLAG%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY      AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE1          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE1%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE2          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE2%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE3          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE3%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE4          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE4%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE5          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE5%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE6          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE6%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE7          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE7%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE8          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE8%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE9          AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE9%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE10         AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE10%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE11         AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE11%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE12         AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE12%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE13         AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE13%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE14         AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE14%TYPE,
    ATTRIBUTE15         AP_SUPPLIERS.ATTRIBUTE15%TYPE,
    AUTO_CALCULATE_INTEREST_FLAG    AP_SUPPLIERS.AUTO_CALCULATE_INTEREST_FLAG%TYPE,
    VALIDATION_NUMBER       NUMBER,
    EXCLUDE_FREIGHT_FROM_DISCOUNT   AP_SUPPLIERS.EXCLUDE_FREIGHT_FROM_DISCOUNT%TYPE,
    TAX_REPORTING_NAME      AP_SUPPLIERS.TAX_REPORTING_NAME%TYPE,
    CHECK_DIGITS            AP_SUPPLIERS.CHECK_DIGITS%TYPE,
    ALLOW_AWT_FLAG          AP_SUPPLIERS.ALLOW_AWT_FLAG%TYPE,
    AWT_GROUP_ID            NUMBER,
    AWT_GROUP_NAME          AP_AWT_GROUPS.NAME%TYPE,
        PAY_AWT_GROUP_ID                NUMBER,                 --bug6664407
        PAY_AWT_GROUP_NAME              AP_AWT_GROUPS.NAME%TYPE,--bug6664407
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE1       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE1%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE2       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE2%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE3       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE3%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE4       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE4%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE5       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE5%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE6       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE6%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE7       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE7%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE8       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE8%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE9       AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE9%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE10      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE10%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE11      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE11%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE12      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE12%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE13      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE13%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE14      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE14%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE15      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE15%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE16      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE16%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE17      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE17%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE18      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE18%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE19      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE19%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE20      AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE20%TYPE,
    GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY   AP_SUPPLIERS.GLOBAL_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY%TYPE,
    BANK_CHARGE_BEARER      AP_SUPPLIERS.BANK_CHARGE_BEARER%TYPE,
    MATCH_OPTION            AP_SUPPLIERS.MATCH_OPTION%TYPE,
    CREATE_DEBIT_MEMO_FLAG      AP_SUPPLIERS.CREATE_DEBIT_MEMO_FLAG%TYPE,
    PARTY_ID            NUMBER,
    PARENT_PARTY_ID         NUMBER,
        JGZZ_FISCAL_CODE                VARCHAR2(20),
        SIC_CODE                        VARCHAR2(30),
        TAX_REFERENCE                   VARCHAR2(50),
    INVENTORY_ORGANIZATION_ID   NUMBER,
    TERMS_NAME          AP_TERMS_TL.NAME%TYPE,
    DEFAULT_TERMS_ID        NUMBER,
        VENDOR_INTERFACE_ID     NUMBER,
    NI_NUMBER           AP_SUPPLIERS.NI_NUMBER%TYPE,
    EXT_PAYEE_REC           IBY_DISBURSEMENT_SETUP_PUB.EXTERNAL_PAYEE_REC_TYPE,
    -- Bug 7437549 Start
        EDI_PAYMENT_FORMAT         AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.EDI_PAYMENT_FORMAT%TYPE,
        EDI_TRANSACTION_HANDLING   AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.EDI_TRANSACTION_HANDLING%TYPE,
        EDI_PAYMENT_METHOD         AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.EDI_PAYMENT_METHOD%TYPE,
        EDI_REMITTANCE_METHOD      AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.EDI_REMITTANCE_METHOD%TYPE,
        EDI_REMITTANCE_INSTRUCTION AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.EDI_REMITTANCE_INSTRUCTION%TYPE
        -- Bug 7437549 End
    ,URL                            HZ_CONTACT_POINTS.URL%TYPE, -- B# 7831956
    -- B# 7583123
    SUPPLIER_NOTIF_METHOD       AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.SUPPLIER_NOTIF_METHOD%TYPE,
    REMITTANCE_EMAIL                AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.REMITTANCE_EMAIL%TYPE
    ,CEO_NAME                       AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.CEO_NAME%TYPE  -- B# 9081643
    ,CEO_TITLE                      AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.CEO_TITLE%TYPE -- B# 9081643
        ,VAT_CODE                       AP_SUPPLIERS.VAT_CODE%TYPE             -- B#9202909
        ,AUTO_TAX_CALC_FLAG             AP_SUPPLIERS.AUTO_TAX_CALC_FLAG%TYPE   -- B#9202909
        ,OFFSET_TAX_FLAG                AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.OFFSET_TAX_FLAG%TYPE  -- B#9202909
    ,VAT_REGISTRATION_NUM       AP_SUPPLIERS_INT.VAT_REGISTRATION_NUM%TYPE -- B#9202909
    );
```

Edit: Per Anthony's suggestion, I have tried to use a record of my own creation:

```
create or replace package XX_SUPPLIERS_PKG is      
  TYPE rec_test IS RECORD(p1 varchar2(255), p2 varchar2(255));

  procedure test_record(p_rec in rec_test, 
                        x_vendor out SYS_REFCURSOR);

  [...]

end XX_SUPPLIERS_PKG;
```

When I attempt to use this stored procedure and record in cx_Oracle, I get:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object XX_SUPPLIERS_PKG_REC_TEST does not exist
```

I checked the DBA_TYPES view from Oracle SQL Developer, and I don't see any types beginning with either "XX" or "REC"

Here is the code that produces the above error:

```
import cx_Oracle


def main():
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(...)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        rec = connection.gettype('XX_SUPPLIERS_PKG_REC_TEST')
        rec.P1 = "test"
        rec.P2 = "test"
        out_cursor = connection.cursor()
        result = cursor.callproc('XX_SUPPLIERS_PKG.TEST_RECORD',
                                 parameters=[rec, out_cursor])
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()

main()
```

One further note: I have attempted to use the PL/SQL RECORD type that is visible in the DBA_TYPES view. That results in a similar error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object PL/SQL RECORD does not exist
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the record? Can you try using a different record in a package of your own creation? Perhaps use the sample from cx_Oracle as a starting point?

Comment: I think that the problem might be on that line: `P_VENDOR_REC = rec`. This `rec` should be of type `apps.ap_vendor_pub_pkg.r_vendor_rec_type` - where did you define it as such? I see you assign it the value of `rec`, but where did you declare it as such a type (also, tag this question with the proper tag for the language you're using). Check this one here: http://www.shareoracleapps.com/2015/05/api-to-create-supplier-in-oracle-apps-r12-ap-vendor-pub-pkg-create-vendor.html

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I have added the record definition to the question. Most of the definitions in the type come from other tables, so let me know if I can provide further info. I will try using cx_Oracle with a record I create today and get back with you.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I have updated the question with my attempt to use a record of my own creation. Still no luck.

Comment: What version of the database are you using?

Comment: Funny you should ask that, @AnthonyTuininga. I just now noticed in the documentation for the PL/SQL Record sample that this is supported in 12.1 and higher. We're using 11.2.

Comment: Is that version limitation due to choices made in cx_Oracle, or is there something inherent in versions < 12.1 which makes this impossible?

Comment: Its not supported by Oracle -- nothing that cx_Oracle can do about it!